# The YouTube crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, tkinter, youtube

I have coded a program to scrape YouTube data (for educational purposes). When the link of the channel is entered it scrapes the channel name, description of the channel, the videos posted by the channel, number of views and links to those videos.

But I hardly managed to make these things work. I am not sure it is the right way to do it. I know the YouTube API could help but for learning I prefer using only requests and Beautiful Soup.

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
 
 
def channelInfo():
   Link = link.get()
   r = requests.get(Link)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
   channelName = "Channel Name: " + soup.title.string
   firrt = Label(text=channelName,fg='yellow',bg='black').place(x=0,y=0)
   var = None
   var1 = None
   var3 = None
   var4 = None
   placer =0
   placer1 =0
   adjust = 0
   for i in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
       var = i.text
       second = Label(text=var,fg='black',bg='white').place(x=200,y=40+adjust)
       adjust+=20
   desc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"description"})
   DESC = desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8')
   third = Label(text=DESC,fg='black',bg='yellow').place(x=0,y=20)
   for j in soup.find_all('li'):
         var1=j.text
         varr = re.findall('[0-9]+,[0-9]+ views',var1)
         for views in varr:
               var3 = Label(text=views,fg='blue').place(x=650,y=40+placer)
               placer+=20
   for k in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
      links = k.get("href")
      final = Link+links
      var4 = Label(text=final).place(x=750,y=40+placer1)
      placer1+=20
                           
                
 
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('500x400')
gui.title('The Youtube Crawler')
label = Label(text='Paste the link below to crawl Youtube',fg='blue')
label.pack()
link = StringVar()
entry = Entry(gui,textvariable=link)
entry.pack()
channel = Button(text='Crawl this channel',fg='white',bg='black',width=30,command=channelInfo)
channel.place(x=10,y=45)
'''
specific = Button(text='Inform about this video',fg='black',bg='white',width=30)
specific.place(x=270,y=45)
'''
entry.focus_set()
url = entry.get()
gui.mainloop()
```

When the link of the channel is hit, the output will be like this without scroll bars:

[image: example output]

Could this code be improved in any way or can the efficiency be increased?

Comment: it might be eaier to learn by using the API first of all then trying Soup after, the structure is clearer from API. I think any code that scrapes html ends up looking complicated, as it is!

Comment: @LukeBarker Please apologize me. English is not my native language. Could you explain me briefer what you are saying.

Comment: I suggested to simply try the API itself first. Then change to use Beautiful Soup after. I think it is easier that way. Good luck :)

Comment: @LukeBarker That was a good suggestion. I think I should try that suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
```

Importing everything from a module is generally frowned upon because it hampers readability, can cause confusion ("where does `Label` come from?") and breaks useful tools like pyflakes. However it is acceptable with tkinter because it was designed to work like this. Just keep in mind that tkinter is *not* an example of a good Python API.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
```

Nitpick: consider importing standard library modules (`re` here) first.

```
def channelInfo():
```

PEP8: `channel_info`, not `channelInfo`.

```
   Link = link.get()
```

PEP8: `link`, not `Link`. Variable names that start with an uppercase character are reserved for classes, like `BeautifulSoup`. I'm going to stop reporting all PEP 8 violations. Use a tool like flake8: it will help you write better code which will be easier to read by other Python developers. Consider a tool like yapf which will try to do this by itself.

```
   r = requests.get(Link)
```

Check the status code. The `Link` variable was not useful here.

```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
   channelName = "Channel Name: " + soup.title.string
   firrt = Label(text=channelName,fg='yellow',bg='black').place(x=0,y=0)
```

`firrt`? What does this mean? Also, this shows that you're completely mixing your interface with the crawling. It's fine here, but for a larger program you would want to separate concerns: first retrieve the data structure, and then show it to your user. A number of design patterns exist for this, one example being MVC in web applications. Using a better GUI framework (other than tkinter) would probably make this easier, but I don't know any good GUI framework in Python (maybe some exist though).

```
   var = None
   var1 = None
   var3 = None
   var4 = None
```

You can do `var, var1, var3, var4 = None, None, None, None`. But when I see this I ask myself many questions. Why so many `var`? What do they mean? Why did you not chooose a descriptive name? Why no `var2`? Are they different variables or should they go into a list? Your main goal when writing code should be to make sure anyone reading you (including your future self) should not be wondering what's going on.

```
   placer =0
   placer1 =0
   adjust = 0
   for i in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
```

`i` is a bad name: it should only be used for numerical loops, but they should be rare in Python. Also, Use a constant to make your class filtering clearer and shorter insteading of hardcoding the value, like `VIDEO_LINK` or something. This is very brittle, too, because if someone at YouTube decides they need another class, your code will break. What you can do instead is choosing one class that you think is less likely to change.  `spf-link` [looks like it would be a good choice](https://github.com/youtube/spfjs). But these things are very brittle anyway, so if you want to ensure this continue to work, you'll need to write tests to ensure that for this specific channel, you continue to get the things you expect.

```
       var = i.text
```

Oh, so maybe they are different variables after all. `i.text` is better than `var`, but you can probably find a better name.
           second = Label(text=var,fg='black',bg='white').place(x=200,y=40+adjust)
           adjust+=20

Do you need to assign `second` here?

```
   desc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"description"})
   DESC = desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8')
```

`desc` and `DESC` are too similar. Use `desc_list` and `desc`, maybe. The `encode('utf-8')` here is not needed. If you really need this then something is wrong. Tkinter accepts Unicode strings. See the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) to understand better how Unicode works. It's a very important skill for a programmer.

```
   third = Label(text=DESC,fg='black',bg='yellow').place(x=0,y=20)
   for j in soup.find_all('li'):
```

`j` is a bad name.

```
         var1=j.text
```

Sorry, but `var1` is also worse than `j.text`.

```
         varr = re.findall('[0-9]+,[0-9]+ views',var1)
```

Seriously? `varr`? I'll stop whining about bad names, but please do something about it. :)

```
         for views in varr:
               var3 = Label(text=views,fg='blue').place(x=650,y=40+placer)
               placer+=20
   for k in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
      links = k.get("href")
      final = Link+links
      var4 = Label(text=final).place(x=750,y=40+placer1)
      placer1+=20



gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('500x400')
gui.title('The Youtube Crawler')
label = Label(text='Paste the link below to crawl Youtube',fg='blue')
label.pack()
link = StringVar()
entry = Entry(gui,textvariable=link)
entry.pack()
channel = Button(text='Crawl this channel',fg='white',bg='black',width=30,command=channelInfo)
```

You're going to block everything while the requests are done. I think using threads could help, but that's probably overkill here.

```
channel.place(x=10,y=45)
'''
specific = Button(text='Inform about this video',fg='black',bg='white',width=30)
specific.place(x=270,y=45)
'''
```

Don't use `'''` for block comments but `#` in front of each line.

```
entry.focus_set()
url = entry.get()
gui.mainloop()
```

This section of the code is specific to Tkinter, which is good. I don't know the API so I can't tell if something could be better.

Oh, and thanks for the screenshot, the app looks quite good for not that much code. Congratulations! Don't feel demotivated by all my comments, you don't need to improve everything at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. One question why shouldn't I use multi-line comments? Is there any specific reason behind it?

Comment: You can use multi-line comment, but use # for each line. `'''` is not designed for multi-line comments, but for multi-line strings.